# Flask-WTF form not getting the data

Tags: python, validation, flask, flask-wtforms

The other forms seems to work fine except for this. There is no error but then again there is no data being taken from that form. I am sure I did everything fine.
Here is my HTML code, I'm using Flask-WTF:

```
<form method="POST" action="/dashboard/{{user}}/{{school}}/">

{{ update_form.csrf_token }}
          {{ wtf.form_field(update_form.day) }}
          <label>Select Time*</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="get_time">
          {% for day, time, subject, room in my_schedule %}
                  <option>{{time}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
          </select><p> </p>
          {{ wtf.form_field(update_form.subject) }}
          {{ wtf.form_field(update_form.room) }}
          {{ wtf.form_field(update_form.submit_update, class="btn btn-success",
          style="position:relative; left:75%;") }}

</form>
```

Here is my Python code, I just wanted to see if the data is obtainable but it turns out it's not getting any data at all.

```
if request.method == 'POST' and update_form.validate_on_submit():
        get_day = update_form.day.data
        get_time = request.form['get_time']
        get_subject = update_form.subject.data
        get_room = update_form.room.data
        print(get_day, get_subject, get_time, get_room, user, school)
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard', user=user, school=school))
```

I am also wondering if Flask actually imposes a limit for forms every page, just to let you know I have several forms on one page, and I'm thinking if it's because of that. I do have the forms on page because I'm using tabs instead of different hmtl file for every link.